# what can be the code of the function to display the five text inputs from the prompt

Tags: javascript, html, function

I'm trying to store the five text that was inputted from the prompt. I need to know the code for how to display each name and the order that was inputted

I'm expecting that the names that was input from the prompt will be displayed in the html file. I can't seem to display it

```
<html>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    names = [];
    function fiveNames() {
      for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        let names = prompt("Enter names:");
        console.log(i, names[i]);
      }
    }
    displayNames(name)

    function displayNames(namesArr){
        var display = document.getElementById('display');
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            let name = 
            names.push(name)
        }
    }
</script>
  </script>
  <head>
    <title>LA4</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Lab Activity #4</h1>
    <h2>Enter Five Names</h2>
    <button onclick="fiveNames()">Input Names</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `var display = document.getElementById('display');` - there is no element with that ID.

Comment: What is `let name = names.push(name)` supposed to achieve?

Comment: Press F12 or right-click and choose inspect. Look in the console. You try to display a name before you have one.

Comment: `let names = prompt("Enter names:");` - that will assign a string value to `names`. You are not actually putting those inputs into an array anywhere right now.

Comment: Also `let name = 
            names.push(name)` is not what you want to do

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues - see also the comments on your question.

- trying to access `name` before it exists
- missing display container
- syntax errors in displayNames

Here is a working version in correct HTML

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>LA4</title>
  <script>
    const names = []; // your array. Use const or let
    function fiveNames() {
      for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) { // use let here too
        let name = prompt(`Enter name ${i+1}/5`);
        names.push(name); // store whatever they entered
      }
      displayNames(names); // here names are defined and stored from the loop - user can enter nothing since there is no testing
    }
    function displayNames(namesArr) {
      var display = document.getElementById('display');
      for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        display.innerHTML += `${names[i]}<br/>`; // using template literals makes life easier
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Lab Activity #4</h1>
  <h2>Enter Five Names</h2>
  <button onclick="fiveNames()">Input Names</button>
  <div id="display"></div>
</body>
</html>
```